# C++ compute partial max's using std::partial_sum

Tags: c++, stl

Is there any way to write something like

`std::partial_sum(nums.begin(), nums.end(), pmax.begin(), std::max);`

? The only way I can get something like this to compile is by wrapping in a lambda

`std::partial_sum(nums.begin(), nums.end(), pmax.begin(), [](int a, int b) { return std::max(a, b); });`

Answer (score 1):

Because `std::max` is overloaded, the compiler cannot figure out which one is used. So you need to explicit specify the correct one:

```
partial_sum(nums.begin(), nums.end(), pmax.begin(),
    static_cast<const int& (*)(const int&, const int&)>(std::max<int>));
```

or

```
const int& (*your_max)(const int &, const int &) = std::max<int>;

partial_sum(nums.begin(), nums.end(), pmax.begin(), your_max);
```